# Join or merging pandas dataframes with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

Hi all TIA for any input.
I would like to join two dataframes, one of which is higher dimensional, by having pandas duplicate the entries of the lower dimensional dataframe for each value of the level of the higher dimensional data frame. E.g., given

```
'''
In [68]: d2nlt
Out[68]:
                                      value
individuals bodyparts coords frame
obstacle1   FrontHigh x      0      927.472
                             1      927.743
                             2      927.999
                             3      928.051
                             4      928.243
...                                     ...
obstacle30  Back      y      857        NaN
                             858        NaN
                             859        NaN
                             860        NaN
                             861        NaN

[103440 rows x 1 columns]
'''
and
In [67]: r3p
Out[67]:
                               value
individuals bodyparts coords
obstacle1   FrontHigh x       13.000
obstacle2   FrontHigh x       12.575
obstacle3   FrontHigh x       12.150
obstacle4   FrontHigh x       11.725
obstacle5   FrontHigh x       11.300
...                              ...
obstacle26  Back      y        1.220
obstacle27  Back      y        1.220
obstacle28  Back      y        1.220
obstacle29  Back      y        1.220
obstacle30  Back      y        1.220

[120 rows x 1 columns]
```

I would like to do

```
d2nlt.merge(r3p,on=['individuals','bodyparts','coords','frame'],how='outer')
```

Or similar and get a data frame like

```
In [68]: merged
Out[68]:
                                      value_x  value_y
individuals bodyparts coords frame
obstacle1   FrontHigh x      0      927.472.   13.0000
                             1      927.743.   13.0000
                             2      927.999.   ...
                             3      928.051
                             4      928.243
...                                     ...
obstacle30  Back      y      857        NaN.   1.220
                             858        NaN.   1.220
                             859        NaN.   ....
                             860        NaN
                             861        NaN

[103440 rows x 1 columns]
```

I have tried most permutations of "how" arguments to merge. And used join.

I can get it to work by duplicating the rows of the r3p dataframe and giving them matching index values for frame, eg 0, 1, and that is fine, but I feel like i had previously done this and had it automatically repeat values for missing keys/levels within the index. Or maybe that was in R.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Remove `frame` from columns to merge: `d2nlt.merge(r3p,on=['individuals','bodyparts','coords'], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')`

Comment: Omg @Corralien you rock! It didn't like that exact line, giving `MergeError: Can only pass argument "on" OR "left_index" and "right_index", not a combination of both.`; however removing the on worked! `d2nlt.merge(r3p, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')` was just what i need. TY! and FYI doing it with `on=` but not left and right index on drops the `frame` level.